# Django haystack elasticsearch problems with autocomplete (and queries with Capital letters)

Tags: django, autocomplete, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I've got a basic django haystack elasticsearch installation running, that seems to be working.. until I hit an autocomplete problem:
It doesn't return autocompletion just the full field. another problem is with data that has CAPS, that isn't normalized (such as usernames..)

MY installation:

django 1.6.4
haystack 2.1.0
elasticsearch 1.3.1
py-elasticsearch 0.6.1

```
class SocialProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    username = indexes.CharField(model_attr='username')
    first_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='first_name')
    last_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='last_name')


    # Auto-complete
    username_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='username')
    first_name_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='first_name')
    last_name_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='last_name')

    def get_model(self):
        return SocialProfile

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Were in the view I return:

```
results = SearchQuerySet().models(SocialProfile).autocomplete(username_auto=q)
```

so when indexing a SocialProfile:

```
username=alonisser
```

when q (the query) is 'alonisser' I get the correct reply, But when I try 'alon' or similiar I don't get any results.

When I access elasticsearch directly through py-elasticsearch (without haystack):

```
es = Elasticsearch('http://elasticsearch.url:9200')
es.search('username_auto:alon', index='haystack')
```

I do get the correct result, so the is stored there and the problem is probably doing something wrong with haystack..

Similiar but different problems is when the searched item has Caps :like 'Alonisser' so searching for 'alonisser' doesn't return any result, but searching for 'Alonisser' does.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already got an answer in the haystack forums but just to bring it out here also.

One way to get rid of the Caps problem is to use a custom prepare method in your index class although my haystack somehow handles it by default :S.

```
def prepare_username_auto(self, obj):
   return obj.username.lower()
```

This will convert all usernames to lowercase when you run 'update_index'. Then you can also turn you user inserted search term to lower also which should produce correct results.

To search for a part of the word you need to use:

```
results = SearchQuerySet().models(SocialProfile).autocomplete(username_auto__startswith=q)
```